# How to click JButton with code in java ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

So, if you had a JButton with an ActionListener coded, I understand if you ran the program and clicked the button, it will process the commands we wrote in the actionlistener. But my question is, is there any way we can CLICK the button on command within java codes? I want my code to click the button for me

Answer (score 2):

Call `doClick()` on the JButton as per it's parent, the [AbstractButton's, API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html).